# What test to write?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I know this is a basic question but due to lack of my knowledge I couldn't start writing test for my application. So here I am trying to learn and understand what to test and how to test based on my application scenario.

```
Class MyController {
  MyService service = new MyService();
  List<String> myList = service.generateSomeList(keyVal);
  model.add("myList", myList);
}

Class MyService {
  ThirdPatryService extService = new ThirdPatryService ();
  MyDao dao = new MyDao();
  public List<String> generateSomeList(Long key) {
    List<String> resultList = dao.fetchMyList(key);
    extService.processData(resultList); //using 3rd party service to process result. It doesn't return anything.
    return formattedList(resultList);
  }
  private List<String> formattedList(List<String> listToProcess) {
    //do some formatting
  }  
}

Class MyDao {
  List<String> fetchMyList(key) {
      //Use DB connection to run sql and return result
  }
}
```

I want to do both unit testing and integration testing. So some of my questions are:

1. Do I have to do unit testing for MyDao? I don't think so since I can test query result by testing service level.
2. What can be the possible test cases for service level? I can think of test result from db and test formatting function. Any other test that I missed?
3. While testing generateSomeList() method is that OK to create dummy String list and test it against result? Like code below Am I creating list myself and testing myself. IS this proper/correct way to write test?

   ```
   @Test
   public void generateSomeListTest() {
     //Step 1: Create dummy string list e.g. dummyList =["test1", "test2", "test3"]
     //Step 2: when(mydao.fetchMyList(anyLong()).thenReturn(dummyList);
     //Step 4: result=service.generateSomelist(123L);
     //Step 5: assertEquals(result[i], dummyList[i]);
   }
   ```
4. I don't think I have to test third party service but I think I have to make sure it is being called. Is this correct? If yes how can I do that with Mockito?
5. How to make sure thirdparty service has really done the processing of my data. Since its return type is void how can I do test it really done its job e.g like send email
6. Do I have to write test for controller or I can just write integration test.

I really appreciate if you could answer these question to understand the testing part for the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They're not really unit tests, but yes, you should test your DAOs. One of the main points in using DAOs is precisely that they're relatively easy to test (you store some test data in the database, then call a DAO method which executes a query, and check that the method returns what it should return), and that they make the service layer easy to test by mocking the DAOs. You should definitely not use the real DAOs when testing the services. Ue mock DAOs. That willmake the service tests much simpler, and much much faster.
2. Testing the results from DB is the job of the DAO test. The service test should use a mock DAO that returns hard-coded results, and checks that the service foes what it should do with these hard-coded results (formatting, in this case)
3. Yes, it's fine.
4. Usually, it's sufficient to stub the dependencies. Verifying that they have been called is often redundant. In that case, it could be a good idea since the third party service doesn't return anything. But that's a code smell. Why doesn't it return something? See the method verify() in Mockito. It's the very first point in the Mockito documentation: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1
5. The third party service is supposed to have been tested separately and thus be reliable. So you're supposed to assume that it does what its documentation says it does. The test for A which uses B is not supposed to test B. Only A. The test of B tests B.
6. A unit test is usually simpler to write and faster to execute. It's also easier to test corner cases with unit tests. Integration tests should be more coarse-grained.

Just a note: what your code severely lacks as is is dependency injection. That's what will make your code testable. It's very hard to test as is because the controller creates its service, which creates its DAO. Instead, the controller should be injected with the service, and the service should be injected with the DAO. That's what allows injecting a mock DAO in the service to test the service in isolation, and to inject a mock service into the controller to test the controller in isolation.

Comment: Thanks .. that really help me to start. My code do have DI I just use new keyword for example.

Comment: @user4035943 here's a good example to get started: http://alexandretricks.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/ninject-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control/